# Laravel + Bootstrap: how to use the yellow warning box

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel, using Bootstrap 2.3.2 when i made validation in this way:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('message', 'Insert the email please');
```

It gave me automatically a very nice yellow box with fade in effect, containint the error message.

Now using this validation:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation)->with('message');
```

That yellow box disapper.
I create a new div to display the errors:

```
 <div class="span12">
 @if($errors->any())
   <ul>
     {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
   </ul>
 @endif
```

How can i add that yellow box with fade-in also here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you confusing the form validation error messages with the session flash messages?

```
->withErrors($validation)
```

will hand over the the form validation error messages to the `$errors` variable, and

```
->with('message', 'Session message')
```

will be available with `Session::has('message')` for one page load only. Notice, in your second line of code you use `with('message')` and then don't actually pass it anything.

If we're just talking validation errors, why not use something like this:

```
@if ($errors)
    <div class="alert">
        <ul>
            {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li>:message</li>')) }}
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
You clarify it to me!

Just the last thing.
How it is used exactly the div for flash message? There are some other classes added to alert?
Because if i put only alert, it appears the flash message how i want, but is too big.
If i try to add a span4 class, then it remains an empty yellow rectangle even without errors to display.
The same if i wrap that div into a span4 div.

Thanks

Comment: I hope I'm understanding what you are saying, but you mean the alert box is still there when there are no errors? Perhaps you could replace `@if ($errors)` with `@if (count($errors) > 0)` to make sure that there is at least one error before generating the alert.